# HighCharts bubble charts customization

Tags: reactjs, charts, highcharts, frontend, react-highcharts

Do you have any solution on how to add additional functionalities to highcharts bubble chart in react like this one [bubble chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9w03.png)?

I need a stoke/circumference around each bubble it has two segments success  in white and failure in red those values comes from series data of each point?

I tried some approaches but no luck.

Could you please guide us on how to achieve this?
another requirement  is there any option to disable bubbles i.e no hover and select functionalities for particular bubbles
thanks

Comment: You can render a `pie` series on the chart rather than the bubble and set his position - demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/uzcqs1rw/ and render a wanted value inside the pie by using the: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#label

Comment: Thanks, we tried like this [code link](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-flower-r99ul) is it a good way to override drawpoints method this way